# How to use a HTML5 Section Tag with GWT?

Tags: html, gwt

I have a GWT project and i wondering how GWT create a HTML5  Tag.

After hours of searching im coming here to ask, is there a way to construct a HTML5 section-tag with GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own widgets.

```
public class SectionPanel extends ComplexPanel implements
    InsertPanel.ForIsWidget {
/**
 * Creates an empty section panel.
 */

public SectionPanel() {
 setElement(DOM.createElement("section"));
}

/**
 * Adds a new child widget to the panel.
 * 
 * @param w
 *            the widget to be added
 */
@Override
public void add(Widget w) {
    add(w, getElement());
}

... etc. ...
```

}

Comment: Oh well! let me try this, looks nice!!

Comment: why HeaderPanel as Constructor? is not SectionPanel?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I copied it from my source... (I edited right now)

Comment: I tried to add a textbox into it like:                                ´TextBox searchBox = new TextBox(); SectionPanel section = new SectionPanel(); mySection.add(searchBox); myDiv.appendChild(mySection.getElement())´ But it dont work!!

Comment: What is myDiv? You should make myDiv.appendChild(mySection) or myDiv.add(mySection). Best was to make a new Question with your code and make a link to this post.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new widget type - you can just use a generic `HTMLPanel` and specify the tag you want to use.

**UiBinder option**

If you use `UiBinder`, your `.ui.xml` file would contain something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
             xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    ...
    <g:HTMLPanel tag="section">
        (your section content here)
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    ...
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**Manual option**

If you prefer to do it programmatically:

```
HTMLPanel section = new HTMLPanel("section", "(your section content here)");
```

The first argument specifies the tag you want to use; the default if you don't specify that first argument is `div`.

In both cases, it will generate this in your HTML output:

```
<section>
    (your section content here)
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any HTML you like in Ui:Binder:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder